# Structure of secrets in terraform script for Cloud Run job

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create the cloud run job resource using terraform and also wanted to add the secrets to the cloud run instance. I am using cloud run module https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-cloud-run/tree/v0.8.0/modules/job-exec

Secrets variable definition is

```
variable "env_secret_vars" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    value_from = set(object({
      secret_key_ref = map(string)
    }))
  }))
  description = "[Beta] Environment variables (Secret Manager)"
  default     = []
}
```

and corresponding to this i am trying to define the variable.tfvars file

```
env_secret_vars = [{
      name = "/app/secret/db/secrets.yaml",
      value_from =[{
        secret_key_ref = {  
            name:"secret name in secret manager",
            key:"version in secret manager"
        }
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

But I am getting below error

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on .terraform\modules\job\modules\job-exec\main.tf line 41, in resource "google_cloud_run_v2_job" "job":
│   41:             dynamic "value_from" {
│
│ Blocks of type "value_from" are not expected here.
╵
```

I am new to the terraform and not getting how to fix this.

Comment: The error message refers to a `dynamic` block not present in the question, but also if that resource does not support that block type then you definitely would not be allowed to specify it.

Comment: the dynamic block is present in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-cloud-run/blob/v0.8.0/modules/job-exec/main.tf. I didn't specify any dynamic. My understanding is that i need to provide the variable and and pass those variable to the gcp provided module and it will create cloud run job with secrets that i am passing in variable.tfvars file and currently that structure seems wrong.

Comment: @Gourav were you able to figure this out? I'm trying to use the exact module and getting the same error as above.

Comment: Yes, I copied the source code of Terraform and fix the issue, and used it. Here is the pull request https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-cloud-run/pull/136.  Please check the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue using the following TF version:

```
Terraform v1.5.6
on darwin_arm64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.79.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google-beta v4.79.0
```

Here's an example from the implementation

```
      ...your cloudrun stuff ...
      env_secret_vars = [
    {
      name = "NEW_RELIC"
      value_from = [
        {
          secret_key_ref = {
            name = "SECRET_NAME"
            key  = "latest"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name = "JWT_KEY"
      value_from = [
        {
          secret_key_ref = {
            name = "SECRET_NAME"
            key  = "latest"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name = "REDIS"
      value_from = [
        {
          secret_key_ref = {
            name = "SECRET_NAME"
            key  = "latest"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```